# debian recover fail from postinst script

Tags: bash, debian, dpkg

I'm a little stuck in a postinst file for Ubuntu.
The problem is when upgrading the package. I have some sqlite databases (marked as config files to save them from upgrades) in which I want to modify in a specific version (add some columns). As only I want to modify the database when installing an specific version (for example from version 3 or older to 4) I check if $2 is not null.

The approach to make the database upgrading is as follows:

- first I make a backup of the databases
- make new table
- Then I alter the tables
- copy the rows from the old table to the new one

The problem is if something goes wrong, the database already will be modified but the package will be at the new version (the four) with config version at 3. If I want to try install again the package in order to get the package ok, the postinst will fail because the database was already modified.
One thing that came to my mind was unset -e, but I find this very unpleasant.

I've searched in the documentation about how to revert fails from postinst, such as if it's called another script with different arguments, but in the documentation Debian says nothing useful.
Maybe the postinst script is not the best place to modify databases?

Thanks

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is check if the field already exists on the table, and alter in that case.
That is not dependent on if this is an upgrade or not.

Like this for example:

```
if sqlite3 /collection.db '.schema media' | grep -q 'new_field text' ; then
  echo field already exists, continuing
else
  sqlite3 /collection.db 'alter table media add column new_field text'
fi
```

---

Also, I would recommend the database schema to be manipulated by the application, and not dpkg.
Imagine that the user might restore a backup from an older version and "break" your software.
It should be clear to the user that the database of older versions is incompatible with the newer version.

I would recommend you to search the internet for help in creating a "migration plan".
Basically that means that you keep track of what "version" the database is and apply sequentially the database modifications when needed, in a way that is very similar to how a patch works.